# Generating reports through custom link which works in Lightning as well as Classic

Tags: lightning, parameters, salesforce-classic, custom-reports, custom-link

I want to create a custom link to navigate to a report mentioned based on the parameter passed to it but for creating a custom link which navigates to a report in **Classic** we need to pass the parameter as **'?pv0='** but in **lightning** the parameters need to be in the format of **'?fv0='**.

Is there any work around or do i need to create two custom links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameterized report links designed for Classic do not work in Lightning, and those designed for Lightning do not work in Classic.

There's a solution for hyperlink formula fields, but it doesn't work for Custom Links. To make a hyperlink formula field work in both environments, you embed a formula expression that looks at the `$User.UIThemeDisplayed` context variable, which is "Theme4d" on Lightning. The formula can then conditionally render a link that works for Lightning or for Classic. (Here's a [fuller explication](https://biggerboatconsulting.com/supporting-report-filter-url-hacks-in-lightning-and-classic/), not by me).

Unfortunately, applying this solution to Custom Links just plain doesn't work - fields and text that are merged into a Custom Link from a formula expression are URL-escaped, which destroys the link if you try something like

```
{! IF($User.UIThemeDisplayed="Theme4d",
"/lightning/r/Report/MY_ID/view?fv0=" & Account.Id ,
"/MY_ID?pv0="& Account.Id ) }
```

This just yields

> You have sent us an Illegal URL or an improperly formatted request.
>
> %2F00O0b000005xXXXXXX%3Fpv0%3D0010b00002XXXXX

(Note the URL escaping).

I've tried a number of routes around this but haven't found anything that actually works.

The delivered [Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000LksFQAS) for parameterized report links in Lightning suggests that this situation will probably not be fixed:

> Current solution in Classic is not changing, but it was something we never officially supported.